# How big can a 64bit signed integer be?

Tags: integer, 64-bit

In [redis](http://redis.io/commands/hincrby),

> The range of values supported by
>   HINCRBY is limited to 64 bit signed
>   integers.

And I'd like to know how big can that 64 bit signed integer be.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This article is good for more information about this topic: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29)

So the answer to the question should be:
From -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, 
or from −(2^63) to 2^63 − 1

The highest positive number stored in a signed int is represented binary as

**----- 63 ones -----**

```
0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

If you think carefully you can find out that this number is exactly 2^63 - 1.

Comment: Also, check out the Wikipedia page: [9223372036854775807](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807)

Comment: like your 63 ones comment, was about to count :)

Comment: @user1767754 don't review code based on comments. ;)

Comment: Or, in a speak-friendly version: nine quintillion two hundred twenty three quadrillion three hundred seventy two trillion thirty six billion eight hundred fifty four million seven hundred seventy five thousand eight hundred and seven :-)

Comment: 9.2 Exabytes.   http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/9/11/how-big-is-a-petabyte-exabyte-zettabyte-or-a-yottabyte.html

Answer (score 9):

A signed integer ranges from size −2^(n−1) through 2^(n−1) − 1 so in this case the maximum value would be 2 ^ 63 - 1 or 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Answer (score 1):

```
    Formula   

    2^(n-1) is the formula of the maximum value of a Bigint data type.

    In the preceding formula N is the size of the data type. The ^ operator calculates the power of the value.

    Now determine the value of N in Bit:

Select (max_length * 8) as 'Bit(s)' from sys.types Where name = 'BIGInt'
=64 Bits
```

Range:: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807