# check for uint64_t overflow in a loop

Tags: c, sequence, multiplication, integer-overflow

I have a C-method which calculates the `k`-th number of the collatz-sequence of `n`.

If n is / gets bigger than 64-Bit the method may return 0.

My approach however has a lot of false positives.
How can a check for an 64 Bit overflow better?

```
uint64_t collatz_K(uint64_t n, uint64_t k) {

    while (k>0){

        if(n > (UINT64_MAX / 3)-1){
           return 0;                   // check if overflow occurs.
        } if(n==1 && k%2==0){
           break;                      //premature break of the method if the end of the sequence is reached.
        }
        else{
            if(n%2 == 0){
                n = n >> 1;
            }else {
                n = 3*n +1;
            }                
            k--;
        }
    }
    return n;    
}
```

Comment: You need to move your check before making the problematic calculation that is into the nested  `else` clause. Because in the other cases there is no danger of overflow.

Comment: Please read my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46442848/7733418 on a similar question. I think it might help you (without actually proposing that it is a duplicate of this question).

Comment: Off-topic, but I'd say poor formatting style... 1. If one of if/else (or a chain of) needs parentheses I strongly recommend adding to all of. 2. as you `break` within the if anyway I wouldn't add an `else` at all (some consider doing so bad style but that's debatable...). Now just a matter of personal taste (really?), but I personally would prefer `for(;k > 0; --k)` – no change of control flow, but the actual loop parts aren't scattered around code.

Comment: @HeapUnderStop Off topic, why do you check for `n==1 && k%2==0`? Isn't it enough to check for `n==1`? It's at least what I see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: Logically `(UINT64_MAX / 3) - 1` ought to be `(UINT64_MAX - 1) / 3`, but it doesn't matter because the value is the same for integer division (because `UINT64_MAX` is divisible by 3, as is 2^(2n)-1 for n∈ℤ⁺).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do two things:

1. Apply the check for overflow only in the case when you calculate `3*n+1`.
2. Use `n > (UINT64_MAX - 1) / 3` instead of `n > (UINT64_MAX / 3) - 1`.

```
uint64_t collatz_K(uint64_t n, uint64_t k) {
    for (; k>0; --k) {
        if (n==1 && k%2==0) {
           break; // premature break of the method if the end of the sequence is reached.
        }
        
        if(n%2 == 0){
            n = n >> 1;
        } else {
            if (n > (UINT64_MAX - 1) / 3)
                return 0; // Overflow will occur
            
            n = 3*n + 1;
        }                
    }
    return n;    
}
```

If your multiplication factor wasn't a compile-time constant (3) but something known only in runtime, you could have used one of the other overflow check approaches suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/catch-and-compute-overflow-during-multiplication-of-two-large-integers).

Comment: A third approach is to check for overflow before the operation, as was done in OP's original code (but in the wrong place; it should have been done in the `else` part). Admittedly, that was one of the answers in the question you linked, but it's better if the division is done at compile time as in OP's original code.

Comment: @IanAbbott Actually, you are right. Since the multiply factor is hard-coded, it's enough to check in compile time. All he had to do is moving the check.

Comment: I've completely revamped the answer.